# Does a Wimshurst machine work fine with normal glass disks?

Tags: high-voltage, generator, static

I want to build my own Wimshurst machine and I cannot find plexiglass disks.

However, in our town there is somebody that cuts normal glass circles–so I wonder if normal glass disks would replace plexiglass/plastic disks and will make a Wimshurst machine work fine.

Will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built my own Wimshurst machine.  Along the way, I read a lot of stuff.  From what I've read, glass works but is not recommended.  It is heavy, it is hard to attach to the axles, and it tends absorb humidity, which limits the voltage you can generate.  [Example of someone who tried using glass.](http://www.asciimation.co.nz/bb/2008/04/19/building-a-wimshurst-machine)

Plexiglass is easy to cut.
All you need is rod with two holes.  The holes are separated by the radius of the desired disk.  In one hole, you put a screw that goes through a hole in you plexiglass sheet.  In the other end, you put a screw that you have filed to a knife blade.  Screw your rod to the plexiglass sheet, then patiently run the sharpened edge around and around until it cuts through.

[This guy built his much like I built mine,](http://makezine.com/projects/the-wimshurst-influence-machine/) though his looks nicer.

This is mine with hand cut plexiglass disks:
[image: Wimshurt]

It can make sparks about 3 centimeters long without a capacitor.  As you can see, it doesn't even have capacitors, though I think the large surface area of the rods makes up for that a little.

My biggest problems were bearings and contacts.
I ended up buying two sets of replacement wheels for "heelys."  I was going to buy some rollerblade wheels, but the heelys wheels were on close out, and I got them for like a buck a pair (just the wheels.)

I ended up using "whiskers" of stranded copper wire for the pickups.  I just taped them to the metal parts with black electrician's tape.

Comment: Thank you. I also built a wimshurst machine already, but now I want to build a bigger one. Good to know the normal glass it not recommended. I will keep searching for plexiglass, but I couldn't find little pieces only big ones (6 metters x 3 metters or so).

Comment: I bought mine at a local hardware and buliding goods store.  They had pieces from 12"x12" up to 36"x36".  It was in a section for hobby supplies, and they had it in a bunch of colors.  All I can recommend is to keep looking.

Comment: You might ask if the store will sell you a smaller piece.  I once had to replace the glass in a cabinet, and just asked the hardware store to order a piece that was cut to the right size.  They sold it to me by the surface area, and didn't even charge for the special order.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep searching. Your machine looks good too! :)

Comment: My machine is industrial butt-ugly, though it does work :).  It was nice of you to say it looks good, though.